# WordPress post views from the_views as a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables

I am using the WordPress plugin WP-PostViews to display the number of views a post has. I am using this code and it works great:

```
<?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); }?>
```

The thing I want to do is to use this number of post views as a variable but I can't get it working. So far I have tried:

```
<?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { $variable = the_views(); } ?>
```

and

```
<?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { $variable = the_views(); } else { $var = 0; } ?>
```

No success so far. Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `the_views()` echos instead of returns. You can get a return by setting the first argument to `false`. Example:

```
<?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { $variable = the_views(false); } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working now :)